# ¿Como generar miniaturas de un video .mp4?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estoy tratando de generar una lista de miniaturas en base de una lista de videos que tengo en mi servidor, hago una comunicación con json para obtener la lista de la ruta de los videos y asi poder reproducir, ahora se tiene previsto el mostrar una lista de todos los videos, para esto se tiene que mostrar en forma de miniaturas, mas o menos asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la imagen ya tengo la lista, pero necesito ahora es generar una miniaturas de los vídeos, la forma en como me devuelve el json es el siguiente:

```
{"list":[{"VIDEO":"VID-20180510-WA0015.mp4","URL":".\/assets\/archivos\/Video Intro\/VID-20180510-WA0015.mp4","ID":"34","DURACION":"24"},{"VIDEO":"video_35.mp4","URL":".\/assets\/archivos\/Video Intro\/video_35.mp4","ID":"48","DURACION":"8"},{"VIDEO":"video_34.mp4","URL":".\/assets\/archivos\/Video Intro\/video_34.mp4","ID":"47","DURACION":"2"},{"VIDEO":"video_29.mp4","URL":".\/assets\/archivos\/Video Intro\/video_29.mp4","ID":"45","DURACION":"3"},{"VIDEO":"video_33.mp4","URL":".\/assets\/archivos\/Video Intro\/video_33.mp4","ID":"46","DURACION":"3"}]}
```

URL es la la ruta del video en el servidor, este proyecto lo estoy trabajando con codeigniter 3.

Alguien me podría decir como generar esas miniaturas.

Comment: yo haria un servicio que llamara a ffmpeg (u otro encoder), le pasaria el video y con las instrucciones del ffmpeg, generaria la miniatura (lo normal suele ser una imagen, no un video miniatura). Revisa como llamar a ejecutables externos, para ver como llamar a ffmpeg.

Comment: pero es una lista de video de alrededor de 20 videos o mas, para la generación de esas miniaturas con ffmpeg se tendrían que almacenar en una carpeta del servidor, y la cosa es como se generara dichas imagenes, puesto que se tendría que relacionar con el video para mostrar una alerta que hace referencia al video, la cuestion es que ya e trabajado con ffmpeg y el gran inconveniente es el tiempo en el que se demora en compilar las diferentes operaciones que realiza, la duda es si existirá una una opcion un poco mas ligera o mas facil que ffmpeg,

Comment: esa accion de generar el video deberia llevarla un consumidor de una cola (tipo rabbitmq), para que hicieras el almacenamiento del video por una parte y luego, mientras tando, otro proceso se encargara de generar la miniatura. Si no recuerdo mal, ffmpeg tambien permite acceder a videos desde url, pero seria cuestion de mirarlo. Por otra parte, veo que los videos ya debes tenerlos en el servidor. Con Symfony tienes la consola, no se si en codeigniter puedes utilizarla para ejecutar comandos, seria cosa de crear un consumer y ejecutarlo desde linea de comandos.